# Django datetime timezone not universally applied

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, utc

I have my timezone set correctly in settings.py but it's not being applied everywhere my datetimes are displayed. In my admin dashboard the right timezone is shown on individual entries, but UTC+0 is shown when I look at a list of entries.

One last detail: the wrong timezone is shown when I return self.datetime in the model's __str__ function.

Aside from making a special case, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/01/07/django-with-time-zone-support-and-mysql/) a post about Django timezone issues. You can also use package pytz to make your code timezone aware.

Comment: Look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects) from the documentation.

Comment: a link *by itself* is not very useful (it may stop working one day -- it is common). Provide some context: how it can help for this specific question.

Comment: I know I can adjust the timezone at that spot, but why would it be correct in some places and wrong elsewhere?